# Unchecked Cast While Generating Signed APK

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, serializable

I receive an arrayList intent as follows

```
 val b = activity?.getIntent()?.extras
        returnedArray = (b!!.getSerializable("questions") as ArrayList<bring>?)!!
```

But am unable to build my apk because of this related error

Unchecked cast: Serializable? to kotlin.collections.ArrayList? /* = java.util.ArrayList? */

How can i fix this?

Comment: It's not an error, it's just that it can't check at runtime that the elements of your ArrayList are of type `bring`

Comment: @user, how can i escape it then, it is hindering my apk build

Answer (score 0):

In android to pass a user-defined object around, your class should implements Parcelable instead of Serializable interface.